# How did Iron Man get this?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, iron-man, avengers-endgame

In *Avengers: Endgame*, at the end of the final battle:

> Thanos thinks that he has the Stark Infinity Gauntlet and is going to snap, but he has not because Iron Man has.

What I have missed is when did Iron Man take the

> Gauntlet from Thanos?

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - I think the OP was asking *to* instead of *from*... Do you think that's the correct version?

Comment: @Stark07 Tony never takes the Gauntlet to Thanos though does he and considering the context of "about to snap" I think it's obvious it's about the end of the battle scene.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Precisely. For me the question is kinda odd either ways.

Comment: @Stark07 I think it's just a case of the OP is mistaken about what happens in that moment in the scene. I answered to address the mistake.

Comment: @Rafa Not sure if you wanted to ask when he took the thingy TO Thanos or FROM Thanos. If it's TO Thanos, then the 15minutes preceding that scene explain when the thingy reached Thanos. If it's FROM, he never takes the thingy from Thanos at all. Either case, Not sure what you're trying to ask here!

Comment: Your edit changed the meaning of the question and so made the answers invalid. It's fine to leave the mistake in the question :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

#### He never took the Stark Infinity Gauntlet from Thanos, he just took the Infinity Stones, presumably by using nano technology, and then used an Infinity Gauntlet built into his suit.

The Stark Infinity Gauntlet is still being worn by Thanos but the Infinity Stones are missing from it.

[image: Thanos looks at the empty Stark Infinity Gauntlet he is wearing]

Then we see Tony in control of the Infinity Stones with a Infinity Gauntlet built into his suit, presumably created using his nano technology that is present in his Mark 85 suit.

[image: Tony inserts the Infinity Stones into his Mark 85 integrated Infinity Gauntlet]

Comment: Avengers : Age of Endgame :P

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot thanks for the info and the images! Your're right in the "gauntlet-stones" thing, I have edited the question. Despite your theory convince me, I think that it's a bad decision not making this scene (probably one of the most important of the film, if not  of the saga) more explicit and let the fan imagine how occurred as there is nothing in the film to image how Ironman take the stones from Thanos gauntlet

Comment: @RafaRomero It's actually incredibly explicit. The large gauntlet is made with nano-technology, as is Tony's suit. I've not met a single person who was confused about how he got the stones.

Comment: @Parrotmaster I was not talking about the gauntlet. I was talking about the moment when Iron-Man takes the stones. This is explicit at all

Comment: But ironman went to thanos and was doing something with his gauntlet then he gets the stones. I don't see anything confusing about what happened

Comment: @RafaRomero Yeah, the stones that are IN the gauntlet.

Comment: @RafaRomero: He pretended to attack Thanos as a diversion, and took the opportunity to steal the stones. Diversion is a basic tool for magic tricks, so I like to think that he spent the 5 years gap between the movies to entertain his daughter with simple magic tricks.

Answer (score 5):

Adapting my answer to [the almost same question on Movies.SE](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/99632/63559):

Nanotech most likely, possibly with a filament shape retrieving the Stones (*not* the Gauntlet).

Since *Infinity War*, Tony has been going around with nano armor able to shapeshift into various stuff; for instance, a shield when it was introduced:

And at the start of the big fight with Thanos in *Endgame*

> Into an electric transformer of sorts, to channel Thor's lightning into a blast in Thanos' face.

Contrary to the previous armors which could,  for instance, deploy from a suitcase, nano doesn't seem to have a "mechanical" comportment and can shape itself into whatever is needed; why not some filaments retrieving the Stones? Although I don't have a visual, I seem to remember the nano "reforming" itself under the Stones on Tony's arm (forming sort of a third Gauntlet), supporting this theory.

Consider that Thanos wears the Gauntlet and has gone through quite the battle, so he is unlikely to feel them being taken away.

Answer (score 1):

While this was never directly explained in the film, I believe Tony built a "back door" into the gauntlet he created -- one that would, at need, allow him to do exactly what he did, which was to *transfer the stones* from the Infinity Gauntlet he'd built to the corresponding part of his own (nanotech) Iron Man suit.  If you recall, just before Thanos attempted to snap, Stark had grabbed him by the Gauntlet, seemingly trying to pull it off his hand -- it was in this moment, unseen by the camera/viewer, and unnoticed by Thanos, that he activated the transfer.

I think it likely that he hadn't intended, when he built this feature into the Gauntlet and his suit, to actually perform a Snap -- but from what he'd seen to that point during the battle, he had likely concluded that he wouldn't be able to hold onto the stones for long, and the only solution to "I am inevitable" was to Snap away Thanos and all his armies.  He'd seen what the unSnap did to Professor Hulk; he knew it would most likely kill him -- but it was, as Strange had said on Titan five years before, the only way.

Answer (score -1):

Unsure whether OP is really asking about two different things(Based on the original vs edited question)
But either case, he never does.

> He neither takes the gauntlet **to** Thanos, or **from** Thanos.
>  Thanos essentially takes the gauntlet off of the Avengers amidst the chaos. Then Tony takes out the infinity stones from them.